# RxSwift Subject.isDisposed maybe not reflecting the actual state?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Consider the following code:

```swift
class RxDisposeTest : XCTestCase {
    
    func test_dispose() {
        var scope = DisposeBag()
        var subjects = [PublishSubject<String>]()
        let upstream = PublishSubject<Int>()
        
        upstream
            .flatMapLatest { _ in
                let newSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
                subjects.append(newSubject)
                return newSubject.debug("\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(newSubject).toOpaque())").do(onDispose: { print("onDispose :: ", newSubject.isDisposed) })
            }
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: scope)
        
        upstream.onNext(1)
        upstream.onNext(2)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(subjects.dropLast().last?.isDisposed, true) // fails
        XCTAssertEqual(subjects.last?.isDisposed, false)
        
        scope = .init()
        
        XCTAssertEqual(subjects.last?.isDisposed, true) // fails
    }
    
}
```

Running this test prints out the following:

```
Test Case '-[CommonTests.RxDisposeTest test_dispose]' started.
2023-06-21 11:36:30.625: 0x0000600002c34f00 -> subscribed
2023-06-21 11:36:30.625: 0x0000600002c34f00 -> isDisposed
onDispose ::  false
2023-06-21 11:36:30.626: 0x0000600002c34580 -> subscribed
RxDisposeTest.swift:257: error: -[CommonTests.RxDisposeTest test_dispose] : XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(false)") is not equal to ("Optional(true)")
2023-06-21 11:36:32.679: 0x0000600002c34580 -> isDisposed
onDispose ::  false
RxDisposeTest.swift:262: error: -[CommonTests.RxDisposeTest test_dispose] : XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(false)") is not equal to ("Optional(true)")
```

As you can see, checking `isDisposed` **inside the `onDispose` hook returns `false`**.
Also, `debug()` correctly prints out that the first `PublishSubject` is disposed as the second one takes over inside `flatMapLatest`. Is this expected behavior?

The version of RxSwift is 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. That particular subscription to the subject has been disposed, but the subject itself is still viable and can accept `onNext` events.

Remember, a Subject can have many subscriptions attached to it. Just because a particular subscription is disposed doesn't mean the entire subject is. A Subject is only disposed when *its* dispose method is called.

Check out this test:

```
func test_dispose() {
    var scope = DisposeBag()
    var subjects = [PublishSubject<String>]()
    let upstream = PublishSubject<Int>()
    
    scope.insert(upstream
        .flatMapLatest { [weak scope] count in
            let newSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
            subjects.append(newSubject)
            scope?.insert(newSubject) // here we are inserting the subject into the dispose bag.
            return newSubject
                .debug("subscription \(count)")
        }
        .subscribe()
    )
    
    upstream.onNext(1)
    upstream.onNext(2)

    XCTAssertEqual(subjects.count, 2)
    XCTAssertFalse(subjects.map(\.isDisposed).allSatisfy { $0 })
    scope = .init()
    XCTAssertTrue(subjects.map(\.isDisposed).allSatisfy { $0 })
}
```